# SQL join multiple sub-queried columns together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example let's say I have an SQL table with 12 rows that looks like the table on the left below, and I want to create the summary table of aggregated row counts on the right.

[image]

Here is an SQLFiddle of this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee508f/1

I can get each of those 4 summary columns individually with the queries below:

```
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS bad FROM mytable WHERE Quality IN (1,2,3) GROUP BY Product;
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS acceptable FROM mytable WHERE Quality IN (4,5,6) GROUP BY Product;
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS good FROM mytable WHERE Quality IN (7,8,9) GROUP BY Product;
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS great FROM mytable WHERE Quality IN (10) GROUP BY Product;
```

But how can I join these 4 results together into a single table like the one shown in my image? I want a solution that can flatly add on additional columns (rather than having another level of nesting), since in my actual project I have 12 columns like this and deeply nesting that many queries would not be very readable.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted/tabular text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need multiple queries though?

```
SELECT Product,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Quality IN (1,2,3) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
          ) AS good,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Quality IN (4,5,6) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
          ) AS fair,
       ...
       ...
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 GROUP
    BY Product
```